# python -- Converting a string into python list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have a string that contains my data like this:

```
result = "[
           {'service': {'option1': 'abc', 'others': 'blah blah'}},
           {'service': {'option2': 'None', 'others': 'None'}}
          ]\n
          [
           {'rules': {'permissions': 'allow', 'opp': 'evening', 'order': '10', 'self': 'me'}},
            {'rules': {'permissions': 'not allowed', 'opp': 'None\\n', 'order': 'None', 'self': 'None'}}
          ]"
```

I want to convert it into a proper list like:

```
result = [[
          {'service': {'option1': 'abc', 'others': 'blah blah'}},
          {'service': {'option2': 'None', 'others': 'None'}}
         ],
         [
          {'rules': {'permissions': 'allow', 'opp': 'evening', 'order': '10', 'self': 'me'}},
          {'rules': {'permissions': 'not allowed', 'opp': 'None\\n', 'order': 'None', 'self': 'None'}}
         ]]
```

Kindly help me out!
I have tried `.split()`, `.join()` but unable to get the exact format like above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `ast`, ( [Abstract Syntax Trees](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) ) with a minor modification of the string,

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval( '[{}]'.format( result.replace( ']\n', '],' ) ) )
```